Animation film (or tv show) where children run around to build a castle with gargoyles
I remember watching a particular scene when I was a kid (late 90s or early 2000s) where a few kids are asked by a wizard or sorcerer to run in the air. 
As they are running blocks are raised to their feet and stay where they are. They end up creating a huge castle, complete with gargoyles. Does anyone remember which film or TV show this is?

It may be Gargoyles (TV series). It's a 90's animated series where Gargoyles are the main lead and they have many supernatural enemies like magicians (sorcerers) etc and sometimes humans. I think I remember one episode where the evil sorcerer manipulates children.

Probably. I have no memory except for that scene. I would have to watch the episodes to confirm. Thanks.
